# Strange subdivision in Multires modifier

Tags: modifiers

I want to create simple character in Blender using Sculpt. When I add Multiresolution modifier on object and click Subdivide, it will generate unsymmetric figure.

How it looks before subdivision:
[image: Before]

How it looks after subdivision:
[image: After]

Answer (score 1):

I've solved it. I had several redundant vertexes on the right "arm". I've removed them and it works fine.